# IE8 weird behavior with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have an iframe that has a form. When I press the "send" button, a jquery function handles the "click" event and send the form via ajax. The return of the ajax is then written on a div in the document. Simple, isn't? This works on all browsers, except IE8. In IE8, when the ajax "done" function writes the answer of the request in the div, the form become completely messed, as it has no style classes.
Here is the code:

```
<form class="ux-form" id="mailForm" name="mailForm">
    <label for="subject">Assunto</label>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="" />
    <label for="nome">Seu nome</label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="" />
    <label for="email">Seu e-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
    <label for="comentarios">Mensagem</label>
    <textarea name="comentarios" id="comentarios" rows="6"></textarea>
    <input class="btn btn-prime" type="button" value="    Enviar    " />
    <input class="btn btn-prime" type="reset" value="   Limpar   " />
</form>

<div id="reply"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#mailForm').find('input[type="button"]').off('click').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#reply').empty();

            $.ajax({
                url:'faleconosco.reply.php',
                type:'POST',
                cache:false,
                dataType:'html',
                data:$('#mailForm').serialize()
            })
            .done(function(result){
                $('#reply').html(result);
            })
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: so what's in `result`, and what does your html/dom look like before/after you try to insert the results?

Comment: Why don't you just do `$("#mailForm input[type=\"button\").click(function() { ... })`? Nevermind. Giving informations on the data being passed around would be helpful, because I don't want to run an IE in a VM on linux.

Comment: Result is just an answer if the form was sent with success or not (it is a e-mail sender). Before, all fields have correct styles (like borders, position and so on). After, the form seems a form that has no styles (default borders, wrong font sizes, fields inline, etc).

Comment: Just reminding: this only happens in IE8. Everything works fine on all browsers (including IE9 +). Am I loosing something about IE8 behavior?